# input from the user using java

Tags: java, eclipse, input, console, eclipse-rcp

I am creating a console using this method

```
MessageConsole console = new MessageConsole("", null);
console.activate();
ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager()
        .addConsoles(new IConsole[] { console });
MessageConsoleStream stream = console.newMessageStream();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(stream, true));
```

I tried the normal method I use for taking an input but it's not working
Here is the code I tried

[1] This prints 'Enter a string' but doesn't allow you to write in the console

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a string");
String s = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("You entered string " + s);
```

[2] and this prints `null`

```
BufferedReader columnInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        System.in));
try {
    System.out.println(columnInput.readLine());
    // System.out.println("#read mflkerf: " );
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

Comment: What is `MessageConsole` it doesn't belong to standard Java libraries. Also how are you running your application?

Comment: You are using System.in as an inputStream for your Scanner. I think you should try using console.getInputStream() instead.

Comment: @Tonny Madsen you gave this answer in a question but I didn't understand public IPageBookViewPage createPage(IConsoleView view) {
    IOConsolePage page = (IOConsolePage) super.createPage(view);
    page.setReadOnly();
    return page;
}

Comment: @student1234 Tonny Madsen wasn't participating in this question so your massage wont reach him. If you want to contact him you should write your comment under [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17052421/1393766) in your previous question.

Comment: @Raphaël It is not working

Comment: well the scanner part for taking input from console has to work without fail.There is nothing wrong in the code for scanner part. Now what else are you doing i am not sure.

Comment: I saw this answer that belongs to my question but I can't understand how to use it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441986/eclipse-rcp-messageconsole-how-to-allow-user-to-input-and-handle-this-listener  Any help please ?

Comment: @zerocool see the question above .. it says that MessageConsole is read only and it doesn't allow input